# How does this setTimeout get called before Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

So I've been studying the event loop, and the micro/macro task queues for the past day. And I have seen direct contradictions from multiple people about the following code:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("A"), 0);

const futureData = fetch('someUrl') // assume this takes 300ms
futureData.then(x => console.log("B"))

console.log("C")

// output -> C, A, B
// what multiple JS instructors says the output will be -> C, B, A
```

The actual output I get is written above. However, in the course that I'm taking, the instructors argue that since `futureData` is a Promise, it gets pushed on to the microtask queue, and since it gets pushed on to the microtask queue, it will be executed first before any macro tasks such as setTimeout.

But after running it, this is literally blatantly false? Is there something that I am missing here? Why would qualified instructors say this, I am almost certain I am missing a crucial piece of information.

My thinking is that only the resolved Promises will be pushed on to the microtask queue while all pending Promises will have to wait until future event loop rounds.

What am I missing?

Comment: `setTimeout()` versus `fetch() ` isn't a fair test. It would be quite amazing if `fetch()` won the race. Try racing`setTimeout()` against `Promise.resolve("B")` instead.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yeah, in that case `Promise.resolve("B")` always wins. I think it basically boils down to if the microtask has enough time to be enqueued before all the synchronous operations are run.

Comment: I would say it boils down to `fetch()` being a lengthy operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pushing asynchronous tasks to micro/macro tasks would only be done after the WebApis or other threads have handled the asynchronous part and only the callback gets pushed to the Queues, these callbacks would run on the main thread itself.

Since the `fetch` is taking around `300ms`, when the stack is empty, the promise callback isn't present in MicroTask queue yet but the SetTimeout one is present in macro.